# Multiple Monitors: Monitor not turning on

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I'm having trouble configuring my laptop display with the external monitor. I use the laptop most at home where I connect it to an external monitor and turn the display off. However I still need to use it "unplugged" or use both monitors from time to time.

Problem 1: When I unplug the monitor the laptop display doesn't turn on automatically. Even I boot the laptop with monitor unplugged it turns itself off after login if I have used it with monitor last time.

Problem 2: Is there any shortcut for easily switching between "mirrored" display, extended display and turning display on and off (Like WinKey+P on Windows?)

I have an Intel HD Graphics 4000 video card and use gnome-shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using the FN+F8 shortcut multiple times until I get the desired configuration. Shortcut may be different on other laptop brands.